# Using a paramaterized decorator for recording methods in a class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I realize much ink has already been spilled on decorators, but I can't find another question which exactly covers this. I have a class, and I would like to 'tag' some of the methods in that class using a decorator. In theory this is straightforward since decorators run when the class is defined. However, I also need to record some user-entered parameters from this decorator. So something like this:

```
@classmethod
def record_func(cls, is_function_special):
    def wrapped(func):
        return func 
    cls.recorded_functions.append((func, is_function_special))
    return wrapped

class TestClass:
    recorded_functions = []

    @record_func(False)
    def func1():
        return 1

    @get_funcs(True)
    def func2():
        return 2
```

The idea being that I would then be able to use this `TestClass.recorded_functions` elsewhere.

The problem (maybe one of many) is that it is only the outer-level decorator (in this case, record_func rather than wrapped) that runs when the class is defined, which has the argument in its namespace but not the function. Is there some clever way to record both the argument and the function?

NB, I've made the decorator a classmethod in this example so that it's generalizable to other classes.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "I've made the decorator a classmethod in this example so that it's generalizable to other classes." Um, that isn't going to work. `classmethod` objects are not callable, they cannot be used as a decorator. It is unclear what you were expecting `classmethod` to do here...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
Yes - this is pseudocode, if it were working I would not have put it here. The intention was that the decorator could be applied to any class and would add the decorated funtions to its recorded_functions attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I like this problem, I was working on a decorator package and I think this could be a great addition. However, let me know if this gets you going in the right direction. It can record every method call, record its args, and kwargs. Then you can do any analytics/aggregation with those results you need.

```
import functools


def bvr_start(arg=None):
    def bvr_start_decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def bvr_start_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            msg = ("STARTED | "
                   "FUNCTION: {} | "
                   "ARGS: {} | "
                   "KWARGS: {} ").format(func.__name__,
                                         args,
                                         kwargs)

            args[0].called_functions.append(msg)


            print(msg)

            return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return return_value
        return bvr_start_wrapper

    if callable(arg):
        return bvr_start_decorator(arg)

    return bvr_start_decorator


class Hello:

    called_functions = []

    @bvr_start
    def test_function_one(self):
        print("Inside my function one")

    @bvr_start
    def test_function_two(self, x):
        print("Inside my function two")


    @bvr_start
    def test_function_three(self, y):
        print("Inside my function three")

hello = Hello()

hello.test_function_one()
hello.test_function_two(4)
hello.test_function_three(y=5)

print("Now print out your called functions")

for called_function in hello.called_functions:
    print(called_function)
```

Now the result of this is:

```
STARTED | FUNCTION: test_function_one | ARGS: (<__main__.Hello object at 0x1038ef2d0>,) | KWARGS: {} 
Inside my function one

STARTED | FUNCTION: test_function_two | ARGS: (<__main__.Hello object at 0x1038ef2d0>, 4) | KWARGS: {} 
Inside my function two

STARTED | FUNCTION: test_function_three | ARGS: (<__main__.Hello object at 0x1038ef2d0>,) | KWARGS: {'y': 5} 
Inside my function three
```

Now print out your called functions

```
STARTED | FUNCTION: test_function_one | ARGS: (<__main__.Hello object at 0x1038ef2d0>,) | KWARGS: {} 

STARTED | FUNCTION: test_function_two | ARGS: (<__main__.Hello object at 0x1038ef2d0>, 4) | KWARGS: {} 

STARTED | FUNCTION: test_function_three | ARGS: (<__main__.Hello object at 0x1038ef2d0>,) | KWARGS: {'y': 5}
```

Now you have a record of the function and the argument. And you can do some more dict like formatting on the final list of called_functions to count how many times each was called with what!

Thanks, and let me know if this helps!

Comment: A more robust way of doing this would be a class level decorator. That creates the called_functions member variable if it does not already have it, and does all the work of recording what is going on and interaction with the class. Then you can access that variable and class interaction history if you needed.

Comment: thanks - this is interesting. So, if I understand this correctly, the functions have to be called before they are added to called_functions? If so this seems to negate the original idea, which was that a decorator could be used as a simple way to record them. If I am having to call them outside of the class, it would be easier to just add them directly to the called_functions variable. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I see. I guess I  need to understand more of the use case here. Because without creating an instance of a class I can get all of its members by name by using the `__dict__` attribute. So above I could do something like `for key, value in Hello.__dict__.items():  if not key.startswith("__"): print(key) `
and now I have all of its members.

Also, what is a user entered parameter in the question? If the method has not been called, how do I get the params? Or does a user entered param not mean a param of a method? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Yes, this would work, except that I would have all of the methods (not just the decorated ones) and also would not have any arguments that were passed by the decorators. I'm actually wondering if what I want is even really possible here. I think it might work with a decorator class but that's probably going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: So if in that snippet above, I am curious if I can go through all the classes members, look at the type and make sure its a function, and then see the decorator attached to it. Then we would have the list of decorated methods we are looking for.

Again, I am having trouble understanding the use case here. If I got a grasp of that I think I could approach this a little better. Thanks!

Comment: sure - and thanks for taking an interest. I have a user-facing class that is composed of instances of many other classes. Some of the methods of these composition classes I would like to make available to the user-facing class. The simplest way to do this would be to 'tag' the functions that should be made user-facing in the manner shown above. The user-facing class can then just load these in directly, eg `for func_name, func in recorded_functions: setattr(self, func_name, func)`